# Shallow copy an array/modify arrays based on condition in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, shallow-copy

```
var a=[0,0,0,0]
var b=[0,0,0,0]
for i in 0..<4{
    var g=i%2==0 ? a:b
    g[i]+=1
    //10 more lines of code about array g
}
```

I want to implement something like whenever i is an even number increment the i position of A by 1, and if i is odd increment the i position of B by 1.
The expecting result is A=`[1,0,1,0]` and B is `[0,1,0,1]`

Here modifying the array `g` will not affect the original array because of deep copy. Are there any ways to modify array `a` and `b` without using `if...else` statement?

Comment: Is this just a toy problem? Because there's a lot of fishy things here. `a` and `b, and the `for` loop have fixed sizes. Also, it seems like your using integers as booleans, which is strange.

Comment: The problem is simplified. The idea is modifying arrays based on condition without using if else statement to reduce duplicate code.

Comment: Do you have a more representative problem? Typical Swift practice is to generate new values instead of mutating existing ones, where possible. For example, in this example I would write this cold as `let a = (0..<4).map { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) ? 1 : 0) }; let b = (0..<4).map { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) ? 0 : 1) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify a value type directly, a possible solution is

```
var a = [0,0,0,0]
var b = [0,0,0,0]

for i in 0..<4 {
    i.isMultiple(of: 2) ? (a[i] += 1) : (b[i] += 1)
}
```

Another solution is to use a class (reference type) wrapper

```
class Wrapper {
    var array = [0,0,0,0]
}

let a = Wrapper()
let b = Wrapper()

for i in 0..<4 {
    let g = i.isMultiple(of: 2) ? a : b
    g.array[i] += 1
}

print(a.array)
print(b.array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[0,0,0,0]
var b=[0,0,0,0]
for i in 0..<4{
    i%2==0 ? (a[i] += 1) : (b[i] += 1)
}

print(a)
print(b)
```

**Result** A=[1,0,1,0] B = [0,1,0,1]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function with an `inout` parameter:

```swift
func modify(g: inout [Int], index: Int) {
    g[index] += 1
    // 10 more lines of code about array g
}
var a = [0,0,0,0]
var b = [0,0,0,0]
for i in 0..<4 {
    if i.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        modify(g: &a, index: i)
    } else {
        modify(g: &b, index: i)
    }
}
print(a)
print(b)
```

You could also put the arrays into a class (reference type) and use that reference to access the array instead of trying to reference the arrays (value types) directly.

[See inout documentation here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html)

[Some info on value vs reference types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)

Answer (score 0):

You are not "thinking value type", yet. For those, copy, modify, and reassign.

```swift
var array: [Int] { .init(repeating: 0, count: 4) }
let (a, b) = array.indices.reduce( into: (array, array) ) { arrays, index in
  let indexIsEven = index.isMultiple(of: 2)

  // Copy
  var array = indexIsEven ? arrays.0 : arrays.1

  // Modify
  array[index] = 1

  // Reassign
  indexIsEven
    ? (arrays.0 = array)
    : (arrays.1 = array)
}
```